# Feature beginning with "w" which allows javascript to access WCF/ASMX services?

Tags: asp.net

There is a term beginning with "w" which is an ASP.NET feature meaning javascript can access WCF/ASMX services. It is not the webmethod or webservice attributes and it is just like scripthandlerfactory.

Any idea what this term is?

Answer (score 1):

What about ... WebScriptServiceHostFactory?
As in System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory

If it found on these pages:
http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/calling-wcf-service-from-javascript.html
http://peterkellner.net/2008/09/14/wcf-web-service-json-vs2008/